# Converting a large list into a numpy type matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a dataset of 456567 records of 256-dimensional vectors in float. I want to read them into memory as a numpy type matrix. I first read them into the memory as a list of lists, which size is 456567 * 256,then I use matrix = numpy.mat(matrix) to convert it into a matrix, but all I got is a matrix of 1 * 456567 size and each of its item is a 256-dimensional list.I try to cut the data into 450k long and the conversion in succeed(return a matrix of 450k * 256 size). So I wonder what is the problem.

My memory size is 8GB and I think it is enough.

Comment: You probably have one or multiple records (maybe the last?) that does not have a length of 256, and thus you cannot create a matrix.

Comment: Seems that's the problem. I made a stupid mistake.Thanks a lot.